# Loop through IE windows until

Tags: powershell

I'm looking at a way to rotate through 4 seperate IE windows (windows not tabs) that contain dashboard data for business viewing.

Now I'm pretty sure I've managed to come up with a "best endeavours" method by using `SendKeys` and rotating via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> - every 15 seconds, using PowerShell.

It seems to work quite swimmingly as these 4 windows will be the only active ones on the PC. However, I'm really struggling to put a bit of "error handling" in there, by killing the PowerShell process in the event the Internet Explorer process crashes for whatever reason.

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: thanks both, managed to get this working with the assistance of LotPings link.